# The application has crashed with an uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' error while displaying FB albums api

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am getting this error while i display the fb albums list using graph path:

> The application has crashed with an uncaught exception
>
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException' ...

Can anyone please help me on this?

```
'GET', function(e) {

        if (e.success) {

            Ti.API.info(e.result);

            if (e.result) {

                var rows = [];

                var data = JSON.parse(e.result).data;
                for (x in data) {
                    //Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(data[x]));
                    var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({});
                    row.textId = data[x].id;
                    var image = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
                        image : "https://graph.facebook.com/" + (data[x].cover_photo || 0) + "/picture?access_token=" + fb.accessToken,
                        top : 0,
                        left : 0,
                        width : 100,
                        height : 100
                    });
                    var title = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
                        text : String.format("%s (%d)", data[x].name, data[x].count) + ' ',
                        top : '50dp',
                        left : 110,
                        width : 'auto',
                        height : 'auto',
                        color : 'black'
                    });
                    row.add(image);
                    row.add(title);
                    rows.push(row);
                }

                tableview.setData(rows);
                }

        } else if (e.cancelled) {
            Ti.API.debug("user cancelled");
        } else {
            Ti.API.debug(e.result);
        }
        activityIndicator.hide();
    });
    $.indexWindow.add(tableview);
```

Comment: I'd suggest stepping through the code with the Studio debugger or add some logs to check the composed values for `image.image`, `title.text`